# Pattern fill in mapview?

Tags: r, r-mapview

Is it possible to fill polygons with patterns (ex. diagonal lines) instead of colour using `mapview`? My searching hasn't turned up anything.

Here's an example that produces colour-filled polygons:

```
library(mapview)
mapview(franconia, col.regions="yellow")
```

Comment: Nope, this is currently not possible. Why is filling polygons with color not enough?

Comment: @TimSalabim Thank you! I love the package. I wanted to map 0's in white, excluded areas in pattern, and the rest with a graduated legend. I could achieve the same with just colours once I figure out how to create a legend scale with uneven breaks (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59913705/how-to-set-an-uneven-sequence-for-legends-in-mapview)

Comment: there are JavaScript add-onns for leaflet that allow for fill patterns, but I don't think any of those is available from R. So I think for now we are stuck with colors...